# "object 'C_stri_join' not found"

Tags: r

I have installed the package 'afex' to do some ANOVA tests.
When I try to run any of it's examples I get an error.

```
> library(afex)    
> data(md_12.1)    
> aov_ez("id", "rt", md_12.1, within = c("angle","noise"),anova_table=list(correction = "none", es = "none"))
```

produces:

> Error in stri_c(..., sep = sep, collapse = collapse, ignore_null = TRUE) : 
>     object 'C_stri_join' not found

The same for `aov_car` examples.

I know there are other questions telling about a similar problem, but they are related to knitr or they advise to reinstall `stringi` or `stringr`.
I've also tried that without any success.
I've also tried reinstalling 'afex' from github, or even Rstudio, but the problem persists.

Any idea on how to solve this problem?

I don't know if it's an 'afex' issue or something related with R or Rstudio.

PD: OK, I've just found that the problem doesn't have anything to do with afex, it also happens when I use the library latex2exp and other.

Comment: Did you install the `stringi` package too?

Comment: OP said they tried reinstalling `stringi` and `stringr` ...

Comment: I'd guess this is related https://github.com/Rexamine/stringi/issues/198

Comment: As I said before reinstalling stringi doesn't solve the problem.